# Do I need a transit visa in Dubai international airport while changing flights?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, paperwork, dxb

I am an Indian citizen traveling from Ukraine to Dubai. After 2.5 hours, I will take another flight from Dubai to Kolkata with a different airline. Would I need a transit visa for this? If yes, then are there any other options? For example, can the meet and greet services help me with my luggage?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Passengers can obtain a transit visa at Abu Dhabi (AUH) or
>     Dubai (DXB) for a maximum of 96 hours. The passenger must: 
>     - transit for at least 8 hours

As such, since you're only transiting for 2.5 hours and have to collect baggage, you will need a transit visa in advance